# How to enable rails assets logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, assets

Rails 6.1.4 now has assets logging disabled by default. How can I reenable them in dev? In `config/environments/development.rb`, I've tried:

```
config.assets.quiet = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

But this doesn't do anything.

Comment: when you run `rails middleware`, did you see the middleware `Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets` ?

Comment: No, I don't. I think that `config.assets.quiet` line was based on an out-dated tip.